# What is the proof that I will not suffer after attaining Moksha / liberation?

Tags: moksha, afterlife, pramana

After attaining *Moksha* there is no suffering. But how long I can be in a state of *Moksha*?
What is the proof that I will not suffer ever after attaining liberation?

Comment: what is the proof that mango tastes sweet ? well, none can prove it to you unless you eat it for yourself.

Comment: How long can you be in a state of moksha? ... Krishna says in Gita 8.20 and 8.21 , that beyond this unmanifested (avyakta mula prakriti) there is another unmanifested eternal existence (nirguna brahm). It is imperishable and eternal. One who reaches that never comes back to material worlds. So i guess it answers your question. He will forever be in a liberated state. Infact there won't be any he or she after moksha. There won't be any sense of individuality then, since you will be united with the greater cosmic spirit Brahman.

Comment: Since you won't come back here on this material platform (which is a place of suffering) you won't experience any suffering upon attaining moksha. And as i said above, there won't be no YOU after moksha,just like waves dissapear into the ocean, your individuality will be lost in the big cosmic spirit Brahman ... Also suffering is due to prakriti or maya. When you the atman is trapped in bodies made of prakriti (flesh & subtle bodies) then there will be suffering. When you the soul discard these bodies during moksha, there will be no more suffering.